# Data table search on column 0 data not on tooltip

Tags: php, laravel, datatable, datatables

I have implemented data table in which an external text box is used to search on column 0 data but there is one issue in which column 0 also contains jQuery tool tip and search filter is also effecting by tool tip data, I want to implement search filter data only on column 0 data not on tool tip present in it.

Here is my js code:

```
$('#stats-search').keyup(function() {
            table.columns(0).search($(this).val()).draw(
                function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
                    var region =$('#slct').val();
                    var column = data[2]// use data for the age column    

                    if (region == column)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }

                    return false;
                }

            ) ;
        })
```

And my table php laravel code is here under:

```
<td><span class="tool_t" data-toggle="tooltip" ><span class="tooltip_text ">{{$single['Town']}}</span>{{$single['PostalCodeOutCode']}} <i class="fa fa-question"></i></span></td>
```

Comment: Does this even work? `draw()` method expects parameters of type boolean or string, not function: https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()

Comment: please post a jsfiddle

Comment: Yes this above is working pretty fine. I just need to restrict search filter on data column 0 except tooltip.